# ImageIO.read() returning a null value

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert a byte array to a `bufferedImage` to display in a `jLabel` but the `ImageIO.read()` property is returning a null value and therefore a `NullPonterException`. What should I do?

```
 InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
    try {
     BufferedImage bufer = ImageIO.read(input);
     ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(bufer).getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel3.getWidth(), jLabel3.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
       
        jLabel3.setIcon(icon);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }`
```

Comment: How have you initialised `input`? Does the file actually exist?

Comment: @KenY-N this should answer your first question: InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(array); it's more likely that array doesn't contain the value Lucian thinks it should

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)), the `read(InputStream)` method ...

> "Returns a `BufferedImage` as the result of decoding a supplied `InputStream` with an `ImageReader` chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The `InputStream` is wrapped in an `ImageInputStream`. *If no registered `ImageReader` claims to be able to read the resulting stream, `null` is returned.*"

It is most likely that the last sentence explains your problem.

---

> What should I do?

So your approach to solving this would be:

1. Check that the contents of `array` is what you expect it to be.
2. Determine what kind of image format it is, and that it is correctly represented.  For example, if the image was stored in a database or sent in a network request, make sure that it hasn't gotten mangled in the process.
3. Check that it is a *supported* image format; i.e. one that there *should* be a registered `ImageReader` class for.

Comment: I am getting the array from a database postgresql. In the beginning I save the array in the DB as a bytea data type and when I make a consult and put those values on the byte[] array and execute a ImageIo.read(Imputstream) return a null value. The image is jpg a supported image. I think that the problem is when I get the values from the database. Any idea?

Comment: I see you have solved it ... and the problem was in the way you were saving / loading the image array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me to solve the problem I going to post the response here to help other.

1.The queries to the database (postgresql) must be preparedStatement because if you are saving an image converted to byte [] this declaration gives you a setBinaryStream functionality and when you retrieve it and add it in a byte[] nothing changes

```
   ////This way save the image and his path (the last is optional)
    JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();
    f.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = f.getSelectedFile();
    FileInputStream s = null;
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
 try {
    s = new FileInputStream(file);
            Conexion();
            PreparedStatement pq = conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO prueba(foto, cam) VALUES (?, ?);");
            pq.setBinaryStream(1, s, (int) file.length());
            pq.setString(2, path);
            pq.executeUpdate();
            s.close();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



   /////This way retrive the info
   byte[] array = null;
   String photopath = "";
   try {
        Conexion();
        PreparedStatement p = conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT foto, cam FROM prueba;");
        ResultSet sq = p.executeQuery();
        while (sq.next()) {
            array = sq.getBytes("foto");
            photopath = sq.getString("cam");
            //jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(array));

            break;
        }
        sq.close();
        p.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(array);
```